# Record video and sound from webcam

Tags: c#, webcam

How can I create a form application in C# that would access the local webcam and record video with sound?

I've searched on Google and I already tried Direct Show and A-frog libraries.

Comment: i found this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3566/DirectX-Capture-Class-Library but it has a problem video lagging... When i recording my video and audio it the audio plays first... I record total 1 minutes but the output video has 2 minutes length... How can I avoid audio/Video lagging

Answer (score 1):

I tried a sample project [DirectX Audio & Video rec in one file](http://directxcapture.wdfiles.com/local--files/start/DirectXCapture_v9.zip) . It is working fine for me.

use the CaptureTest form in the above-referenced code.

You need to change the below code to call the CaptureTest.

```
/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
[STAThread]
static void Main() 
{
    AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    //Application.Run(new CaptureTest());
    Application.Run(new QuickTest());
}
```

Refered through Code Project [DirectX.Capture Class Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3566/DirectX-Capture-Class-Library)

Answer (score 0):

Try OpenCV library. It contains inbuilt functions to take input from local webcam.